# SpriteKit Collision Detection Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have three nodes in my game-

*The Player* -

This is a boat that you drag around using a joystick.

```
let collisionPlayer : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

let apple = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
    apple.position = position
    apple.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: apple.size.width / 2.0)
    apple.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    apple.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    apple.setScale(0.1)
    addChild(apple)
```

("apple" is the boat)

*The Enemy Boat* -

This is a CPU boat that randomly follows the player around.

```
 let collisionNPC : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0


 appleNPC.position = position
    appleNPC.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: appleNPC.size.width / 2.0)
    appleNPC.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    appleNPC.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    appleNPC.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 200)

    appleNPC.setScale(0.1)
    addChild(appleNPC)
```

*The Bullet*
(self-explanatory)

```
let collisionBullet : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
```

(The following code is in TouchesEnded)

```
  bullet?.name = "Bullet"
    bullet?.position = (appleNode?.position)!
    bullet?.setScale(0.05)
    bullet?.zPosition = 1
    bullet?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (bullet?.size.width)!/2)
    bullet?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    bullet?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

To move the bullet I use the code:

```
    // Your code with delay
    if bulletNumbers > 0 {
        let offset = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x - (bullet?.position.x)! , y: touchLocation.y - (bullet?.position.y)!)

        //Stops Bullet from shooting backwards


        //Get the direction of where to shoot
        let direction = offset

        //Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
        let shootAmount = CGPoint(x: direction.x * 10, y: direction.y * 10)

        //Add the shoot amount to the current position
        let realDest = CGPoint(x: shootAmount.x + (bullet?.position.x)!, y: shootAmount.y + (bullet?.position.y)!)

        //Create the actions
        addChild(bullet!)
        self.bulletNumbers -= 1

        let distance = sqrt(pow(realDest.x - (appleNode?.position.x)!, 2) +
            pow(realDest.y - (appleNode?.position.y)!, 2))

        // run the sequence of actions for the firing
        let duration = TimeInterval(distance / PlayerMissileSpeed)
        let missileMoveAction = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: duration)
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 10 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { self.bulletNumbers += 1
        }
        bullet?.run(missileMoveAction) {
        self.bullet?.isHidden = true
        self.bullet?.removeFromParent()
        print("\(self.bulletNumbers)")
        }}
    else if bulletNumbers <= 0 {
      print("reload")

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

        }

    }


}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("test")


}

func setRandomStickColor() {
    let randomColor = UIColor.random()
    moveAnalogStick.stick.color = randomColor
}

func setRandomSubstrateColor() {
    let randomColor = UIColor.random()
    moveAnalogStick.substrate.color = randomColor
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    super.update(currentTime)
    let _:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(1) //

    appleNodeCpuSpeed = CGFloat(1)


    var locationx : CGFloat
    var locationy: CGFloat

    locationx = (appleNode?.position.x)!
    locationy = (appleNode?.position.y)!
    let dx = locationx - (appleNodeNPC?.position.x)!
    let dy = locationy - (appleNodeNPC?.position.y)!
    let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
    let vx = cos(angle) * appleNodeCpuSpeed
    let vy = sin(angle) * appleNodeCpuSpeed


    self.appleNodeNPC?.position.x += vx
    self.appleNodeNPC?.position.y += vy

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.25 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

          self.appleNodeNPC?.zRotation = angle + 90

    }
    //2
```

This works fine. The bullet is launched from the boat to the touch location, however, things start to go wrong when I tried to introduce collisions. Here is my code below:

```
 appleNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionPlayer
    appleNode?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionNPC
    appleNode?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0

    appleNodeNPC?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionNPC
    appleNodeNPC?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionPlayer
    appleNodeNPC?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionBullet

    bullet?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionBullet
    bullet?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    bullet?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionNPC


    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    view.showsPhysics = true
```

Then in my didBegin function I have:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("test")


}
```

Let's start from the beginning. I tap the screen and the bullet is launched. The bullet does not collide with the Player, which is what I originally wanted. However, when the bullet makes contact with the Enemy ship it DOES collide. It goes around the ship and keeps going on to its original destination. I want the bullet to contact the ship and nothing else - no collisions. I would hope to assume that my error here is because of my code for moving the bullet, but i'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want the bullet to collide with the player?  You want it to bounce back when it hits the player?

Comment: I want to make it so (eventually) when the bullet makes contact with the enemy ship the ship's health goes down, and the bullet disappears.

Comment: You are using a wrong definition for SpriteKit collision just as many beginners do.

Comment: Your names are a bit confusing - apple, player, appleNPC - as are your categories - collisionPlayer, collisionNPC, collisionBullet.  If you have the objects player, enemy boat and bullet then have categories playerCategory, enemyCategory and bulletCategory. It will make your code much more readable. Also be clear in your mind between collisions and contacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define unique categories, ensure your class is a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` and make yourself the physics contact delegate:

`//Physics categories`

```
let appleCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 0
let enemyCategory:    UInt32 = 1 << 1
let bulletCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 2

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

2. Assign the categories (usually in `didMove(to view:)` :

   `apple.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = appleCategory
   enemy.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = enemyCategory
   bullet.physicsBody.catgeoryBitMask = bulletCategory`

(Make sure you've created physics bodies for each node)

3. Set up collisions:

`apple.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // apple/player collides with nothing
enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // enemy collides with nothing
bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // bullet collides with nothing`

or even:

```
for node in [apple, enemy, bullet] {
   node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 //  collides with nothing
   }
```

4. Set up contacts

   `bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory // bullet contacts enemy`

Make sure that at least one of the objects involved in each potential contact has the `isDynamic` property on its physics body set to `true`, or no contact will be generated. It is not necessary for both of the objects to be dynamic.

You should now get `didBegin` called when the bullet and the enemy make contact. You could code `didBegin` like this:

```
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
     print("didBeginContact entered for \(String(describing: contact.bodyA.node!.name)) and \(String(describing: contact.bodyB.node!.name))")

     let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

     switch contactMask {
     case bulletCategory | enemyCategory:
        print("bullet and enemy have contacted.")
        let bulletNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
        enemyHealth -= 10
        bulletNode.removeFromParent
     default:
        print("Some other contact occurred")
     }
```

}

Comment: We need to suggest to Stackoverflow to bring back documents, but in a way that we tag common answers to a particular topic so that we can reduce these types of questions from repeating.

Comment: Yep - this pretty much solves *every* "SpriteKit collisions not working" question. I'm almost getting tired of using it and just having to change the node names for each individual question.  Once you get your head around it, you wonder why you ever found it difficult :-) Unfortunately it's more about following a process than just copying some code. Maybe I should look at the community wiki, but it does need tweaking for the specifics of each question.

Comment: What we need is some sort of checklist for the OP of one of these types of questions to follow, to help them eliminate the most common errors.